# Why is the shadow being applied to the text in my view and not the view itself?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a table view populated with 2 labels of text. I want the views to be outlined with a shadow, however, with my current code, only the text gets a shadow. Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NoteTableViewCell
        
    cell.titleLabel?.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.mainTextLabel?.text = noteArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
    cell.mainTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size: 14.0)
    cell.cardView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    cell.cardView?.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    cell.cardView?.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    cell.cardView?.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.cardView?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10,
                                          height: 10)
    return cell
}
```

`NoteTableViewCell`

```
class NoteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainTextLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }

    
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my app:

[image]

Comment: Can you show code for `NoteTableViewCell`?

Comment: @aheze, I added the code

Comment: Is your cardView transparent?

Comment: @TomasJablonskis, I do not think so, under its attribute inspector the opaque checkbox is marked.

Comment: Yea, but what is the backgroundColor?

Comment: @TomasJablonskis The background color is System Background Color, I tried changing it and nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that it was because I had not set a height or width for the view. After doing so it displayed properly